# How are PUT parameters passed to a page?

Tags: http, protocols, put

I can't find a precise answer on that question :

Are parameters which are sent by PUT passed in the URL, or in the HTTP header ?

I think it's the HTTP header, but when I submit my form with the PUT method, it appends the parameters to the URL !

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Are parameters which are sent by PUT passed in the URL, or in the HTTP header ?

Not the headers. It's the same as POST - either the URL or the body of the request. The only difference is the HTTP verb being used and of course the semantics that come with it (UPDATE a resource on the server).

Comment: I didn't know that POST could send data by URL !
Isn't it only in the HTTP request body ?   --- 

So it means that PUT can send data like http://www.example.com?param=value
OR
into the Request Body ?

Comment: Both are possible URL and body. I would avoid it though. I would only use the body.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much !
So it means that in my case, it is the server which automatically put the parameters in the URL after I hit the submit button ?

Comment: What submit button? Are you talking about an HTML web page with a `<form>`. Most browsers support only the GET and POST verbs, not PUT. You will have to use AJAX if you want to use the PUT verb from a web page. And no, it is not the server that is adding anything to the request. It's the client. In the case of an HTML `<form>` this is described in the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html). If you are using `method="GET"` then the browser will add all input field values that are inside the form to the query string. If you use POST it will add them to the body.

Comment: Yes I use a `<form>` to do my tests.
Thanks for the advices !

Answer (score 4):

Your question seems to be about HTML forms. In which case the answer is: they do not support PUT (the browser still sends a POST request instead).

If it's not about HTML forms: it's up to you. For instance, in XmlHttpRequest you can use both.