# PUT method generating error when sending data with multipart form data

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, put

I am sending some data with multipart data in put methos in spring mvc. The sme process is working with post request but generating an error in put request.
this is my code snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)

public Product update(@PathVariable("id") int id,@RequestParam("name") String name,@RequestParam("price") int price @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
}
```

The error generated is:
HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'name' is not present

**type** Status report

**message** Required String parameter 'name' is not present

**description** The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: What is the HTTP Request? I ask to make sure that the `name` parameter is indeed present in your request.

Comment: I am sending the parameters using ARC i.e. Advanced REST Client. I am sending a multipart/form data includeing a file and a raw payload having name=abcd&price=1000

Answer (score 1):

thnx for all to answer the question. I got my answer and that is we can not use multipart/form data with put because put takes a single entry

Answer (score 0):

Please see [How are PUT parameters passed to a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578513/how-are-put-parameters-passed-to-a-page). The parameters must be in the body, not in the URL or the header.

Comment: I am using multiformdata, so How can I send a json request in requestbody