# How is HTTP data sent in PUT and DELETE requests?

Tags: http

In an HTTP GET request, all data is found in the URL.

In an HTTP POST request, all data is found within the HTTP body.

Where is the data in a DELETE or PUT request?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578513/how-are-put-parameters-passed-to-a-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply, as far as passing data with your call goes:

- DELETE should follow the same guidelines as GET
- PUT should follow the same guidelines as POST

Answer (score 1):

From the RFC [7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**4.3.5.  DELETE**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5)
>
> [...] A payload within a `DELETE` request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a `DELETE` request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

> [**4.3.4.  PUT**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)
>
> The `PUT` method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload. [...]

---

For both methods, you can send data in the URL using [path / matrix](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3)
and [query](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) parameters.